# What's the best way to move the TOS and Contact info to the bottom of the Swagger UI page?

Tags: swagger-ui

I'd like to move the TOS and Contact info divs from the top of the page down to the footer.

These are the divs I want to move: "info_tos", "info_name", "info_url", "info_email".

I could just use jquery's .insertBefore() to move them, but I don't know when the UI will be done rendering and the divs will actually exist.

Is there an event that is fired when that is done?

Is there some better way to move those to the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: use the onComplete callback. This is called when Swagger UI has finished rendering.